# If the waves in electromagnetism come from the metric, do waves in quantum mechanics also come from the metric?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, special-relativity, metric-tensor

If we have the Laplace equation with metric $||(t,x,y,z)||^2 = -t^2 + x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ then we get the wave equation:

$$\Delta f = -f_{tt}+f_{xx}+f_{yy}+f_{zz}=0$$

If there wasn't a $-1$ in front of the $t$ then we would not have wave behaviour. So the wave behaviour of photons in EM comes from the (-1,1,1,1) signature of the metric. In quantum mechanics we also have wave behaviour of particles. Does this wave behaviour also come from the $-1$ in the metric, and if so, how?

Comment: The "wave equation" of quantum mechanics is the Schrödinger equation, not the Laplace equation. It's not clear to me what this question is asking.

Comment: I know that the wave equation in QM is the Schrödinger equation. Light is a wave in EM and is described by the Laplace equation with the Minkowski metric. It becomes a wave equation because of the $-1$ in that metric. If the metric had signature 1,1,1,1 (Euclidean space) instead of -1,1,1,1 (Minkowski space) then there wouldn't be any waves. So in EM the wave behaviour of light is directly connected to the signature of the metric.

Comment: In QM photons (and other particles) also exhibit wave like behaviour, that presumably in some limit results in classical EM. So is the wave behaviour in QM also related to the metric signature? If so, how? I don't know if this explanation makes the question any clearer...

Comment: I don't think Maxwell was aware of the Minkowski metric when he formulated his equations.

Comment: Sure, but that is the modern view.

Answer (score 1):

There is no spacetime in classical QM. The only metric is the Euclidian metric for space. Time is not related to space.

The Schrodinger equation in QM has the Euclidian structure for the momentum, they simpl add isotropically and spherically symmetric (with the Euclidian isotropic metric), i.e. As their squares. There you get the second derivatives wrt space. Time arises because the equation basically says that the kinetic (which depends on the squares of the momentum) plus potential energy equals the total energy, so the side of the equation opposite the second derivatives is the energy, with the operator being the time derivative. For fixed energies, i.e., eigenvectors of the time derivative operator you get $e^{iat}$ and the second derivatives give you also the same term as eigenvectors except with space (X,y,z) variables instead of time. The solution then comes out to be the wave function, for fixe energy and momentum, and no force or potential energy. Combine (linearly add) a bunch of those into a wave packet and you get a a general solution. Notice that the speed of the wave is not determined by a constant in the Schrodinger equation, it is not c. There is just no spacetime or Minkowski effect.

So, no in Galilean space it is just a 3D Galilean metric.the symmetries of Galileo and Newton are not those described by a Lorentzian metric. But you can still have waves.

If you go to relativistic QM or Quantum field theory, you are back in Minkowski spacetime and the equations are what you posted.

You can get wave equations and waves in a lot of different theories and equations.

Comment: Your answer doesn't make much sense, looks like you are just jumbling some words together.

Comment: @SuzuHirose Strongly disagree.

Comment: @LewisMiller Maybe I messed up.

Comment: I think this answer makes sense, but it does not fully clear up my confusion. That the speed of waves in the Schrodinger equation is not c is a very good point. However, if you look at the Klein-Gordon equation or Dirac equation you have $\Delta f = m^2 f$ or $\partial f = mf$. Although there is an additional term to account for the mass, it seems that the wave behaviour still comes from the metric. I guess you can summarise the question as: is the wave behaviour of particles actually a relativistic effect? [continued...]

Comment: The Schrodinger equation uses Galilean space, and is not relativistically invariant. However, this does not necessarily mean that the wave behaviour is unrelated to the Minkowski metric, as the Schrodinger equation is only an approximation where the wave behaviour is baked into the equation rather than coming from the geometry, just like how you can take into account some relativistic effects by modifying the Hamiltonian.

Comment: @Jules in QM it is not an approximation, it completely and exactly describes non relativistic QM, with a different symmetry group than the Lorentz or Poincare group. How Schrodinger got to it may have had something to do with a view that it needed to be a wave, or not, that's simply a historical question. Nothing to do with physics. If you mean somehow you get to a form that leads to the wave equation, which has the form you noted, ok, but there's lots of waves in classical mechanics, before relativity, lots of wavy things w/o relativity. Klein Gordon and Dirac are relativistic by design

Comment: It is an approximation in the same sense that people say that Newtonian mechanics is an approximation. You could also say that no, Newtonian mechanics is exact, it just uses Galilean group, but this is just semantics.

Comment: That how Schrodinger got to his equation is a historical question is precisely my point: just because Schrodinger got a wave equation without the wave behaviour explicitly coming from the metric does not imply that this wave behaviour does not come from the metric. However, I would note that *even* historically, Schrodinger first considered the Klein-Gordon equation, but dismissed it because it did not predict the energy levels accurately (now we know that this is because it does not take into account the spin).